# How to send array values to php page using ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to pass some array values to php page using ajax.this is what i have tried.but it's pass only first value.not all the array values

```
<script>
    function priceSub() {
    var price = $("input[name='price[]']").val();

    $.post('db_price.php', {prce:price});
    return true;
    }
 </script>
     <?php   //this is come from another page
            $itemCount = count($_POST["price"]);
            for($i=0;$i<$itemCount;$i++) {
            $op_name=$_POST['price'][$i];

    ?>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $price;?>" name="price[]" id="price"/>
    <?php
      }
     ?>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="suboderbtn" onclick="return priceSub();"/>
```

Comment: use JSON ..http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php

Comment: You are sending one value, right? Also `{prce:price}` should be `{price:price}`

Comment: no this text field show some price values in an array.

Comment: You cant store array in the textfield. In this case, you need to split textfield value with `,` and send each value individually.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to know is you have `{prce:price}`, and use `$_POST['price']`, so you need to use `{price:price}` instead.
However, you can send any number of data via ajax:

```
 $.post('db_price.php', {price:price, data1: "value1", data2: "value2",...});
```

And you can access data with `$_POST['price']` , `$_POST['data1']`, `$_POST['data2']`,... in the php script.

**Edit:**

You can't send array with one text field. For do this, you can separate values with `,` and explode the value in the php script. For example the text field value may be "value1, value2". Now you can use this code for getting array value :

```
$prices = explode(",", $_POST['price']);
```

Now `$prices[0]` will be "value1" and `$prices[1]` will be "value2".

Answer (score 0):

Try using json_encode function :

`$.post('db_price.php', <?php json_encode($_POST["price"]); ?>);`

Answer (score 0):

do like this for posting an array field
Javascript

```
<script>
    function priceSub() {

    var price = $('input#price').serialize();
    console.log(price)
    $.post('db_price.php', {price:price});
    return true;
    }
 </script>
```

html

```
<input type="hidden" value="10" name="price[]" id="price"/>
<input type="hidden" value="20" name="price[]" id="price"/>
```